# Ignoring particular elements in a string array

Tags: java

I am writing a program that that ignores everything between the symbols "/*" and "*/" in a string, similarly as the IDE would in a real life scenario. I'm splitting the string into lines and storing it in an array, I then have a while loop to build words from the individual characters in the current line ignoring the symbols, however it my output isn't quite right.

Below is an example of what i'm trying to achieve.

```
Phrase: The quick brown /* fox jumped over the */ lazy dog.

Desired output: The quick brown lazy dog.
```

Essentially removing everything between the comments.

Here is my current attempt.

```
public class Testing6 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String riddle = "The Quick \n" +
            " brown /* fox \n" +
            " jumped over \n" +
            " the  */ lazy \n" +
            " dog \n";

    String[] lines = riddle.split("\\r?\\n");

    for (String line : lines) {
        int n = line.length();
        int index = 0;
        String word = "";

        while (index < n) {

            char ch = line.charAt(index);

            word = word + ch;

            if (ch == ' ' )  //if ch is empty, word is complete, print word.
            {
                System.out.println(word);
                word = "";
            }
            if (ch == '/' || ch == '*') { // checking for symbols

                index++;
                if (ch == '*' || ch == '/')
                {
                    index++;
                    break; // breaking if symbols match
                }

            }

            index++;
        }

        }
    }

}
```

Current output:

```
The 
Quick 

brown 

jumped 
over 

the `
```

Thank you in advance for any feedback.

Comment: What is your question? If you just want your code reviewed, go to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The candidate needs a fix in his code. It is not really a code review.

Answer (score 1):

I am modifying your answer to display the line as per your expectation. There is no real enhancement done to your code here.

Following are the issues in your code:

1. You are using `println` which prints each string in a new line.
2. You are also printing empty words thereby seeing gaps in the strings in the output.

I fixed both the above problems and it is displaying properly now

```
String riddle = "The Quick \n" +
                " brown /* fox \n" +
                " jumped over \n" +
                " the  */ lazy \n" +
                " dog \n";

String[] lines = riddle.split("\\r?\\n");
String word = "";
for (String line : lines) {
    int n = line.length();
    for (int index = 0; index < n; index++) {
        char ch = line.charAt(index);
        if (ch == ' ') { // if ch is empty, word is complete, print word.
            if (!word.isEmpty()) { // do not log empty word
                word = word + ch;
                System.out.print(word);
                word = "";
            }
            continue;
        }
        if (ch == '/' || ch == '*') { // checking for symbols
            index++;
            if (ch == '*' || ch == '/') {
                index++;
                break; // breaking if symbols match
            }
        }
        word = word + ch; // only non-empty chars are added here
    }
}
```

Output is

```
The Quick brown jumped over the dog
```

Note that the last word may contain extra space based on your input. But I think you can take it forward from here.